# A book/text in Stochastic Differential Equations

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Somebody know a book/text about Stochastic Differential Equations? I'm in the last period of the undergraduate course and I have interest in this field, but my university don't have a specialist in this area. So, I want a book that can introduce me in this field without many difficulty and that permite me study still others more advanced texts. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a free book by Evans:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.berkeley.edu%2F~evans%2FSDE.course.pdf&ei=AhtsUraRJ87qkAfSp4Bo&usg=AFQjCNE53z56RnKcJrcmImNp4BT4egSFag&sig2=xo7gynJelChMeL0-An8adg

This is also a good text:

[http://www.amazon.com/Stochastic-Differential-Equations-Introduction-Applications/dp/3540047581/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1382816460&sr=8-1&keywords=stochastic+differential+equations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540047581)

Comment: There are plenty of other though but you can look at : Karatzas and Shreve "Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus", Protters "stochastic integration and differential equations", or even "Continuous martingales and Brownian motion" by Revuz and Yor and lastly not a book but the blog "almost sure" of George Lowther is really original, self contained, elegant and didactic and treat SDEs.

Answer (score 1):

A gentle introduction to the topic of stochastic differential equations can be found in

[*René L. Schilling/Lothar Partzsch: Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes*](http://www.motapa.de/brownian_motion/index.html)

It covers stochastic differential equations driven by Brownian motion.