# A textbook for a rigorous introduction to Stochastic Analysis with emphasis on stochastic differential equations

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, soft-question, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

I'm looking for a good textbook for an introduction to Stochastic Analysis,  preferably one that focuses on rigour. I am familiar with measure theory and basic probability theory. The direction I am mostly interested in is stochastic differential equations.

Comment: Stochastic analysis is a broad field.  Perhaps you could list some specific topics you want to learn.

Comment: There are already several questions on this site asking for SDE textbook recommendations.  Please see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596317/background-for-studying-and-understanding-stochastic-differential-equations http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028502/what-is-an-alternative-book-to-oksendals-stochastic-differential-equation-an-i http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540641/a-book-text-in-stochastic-differential-equations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

personally i like Chung and Williams. Very clear and unambitious whilst maintaining rigour.

See also my recommended book list on www.markjoshi.com